# Why is Adam trapped in bad/suspicious local optima after the first few updates?

Tags: deep-learning, papers, optimization, learning-rate, adam

In the paper [On the Variance of the Adaptive Learning Rate and Beyond](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03265), in section 2, the authors write

> To further analyze this phenomenon, we visualize the histogram of the absolute value of gradients on a log scale in Figure 2. We observe that, without applying warmup, the gradient distribution is distorted to have a mass center in relatively small values within 10 updates. Such gradient distortion means that the vanilla Adam is trapped in bad/suspicious local optima after the first few updates.

Here is figure 2 from the paper.

[image]

Can someone explain this part?

> Such gradient distortion means that the vanilla Adam is trapped in bad/suspicious local optima after the first few updates.

Why is this true?

Answer (score 1):

The authors describe their belief in Section 3:

> Due to the lack of samples in the early stage, the adaptive learning rate has an undesirably large variance, which leads to suspicious/bad local optima.

Diving further, in section 3.2:

> Adam uses the exponential moving average to calculate the adaptive learning rate.  For gradients $\{g_1,\dots,g_t\}$, their exponential moving average has a larger variance than their simple average.  Also, in the early stage ($t$ is small), the difference of the exponential weights of $\{g_1,\dots,g_t\}$ is relatively small (up to $1−β^{t−1}_2$).

It seems like the root issue is that exponential moving average, while great with many data samples, have too large of a variance with few data samples. It is this variance that sometimes allow the gradient descend in a bad optima.